# How may I follow a specific topic like C#, CSS, or JavaScript?

Tags: support, documentation

There are so many tags, and I want to follow specific tags, so I may be notified if something is added or improved. I can't keep looking through the pages and each topic in a specific tag may every day. There are so many examples; after all, I am only interested in some tags.

Comment: In the dashboard on each section (The "summary" tab) you can select to get notifications on changes in that topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to the [Dashboard page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23) of a tag you're interested in and subscribe to requested topics, improvement requests and proposed changes.

[image]